# Rails 3 Rendering Binary Content

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, blob, binaryfiles

I need to render binary content(images) on web page. I'm saving images in the database with datatype binary. Now I need to iterate available images from the database and render on webpage.

Please check the below code that I'm doing. Icon is the image column name in material.

```
// iterating all materials
<% @materials.each do |material| %>
     // for each material
     <span><%= image_tag(material.icon) %></span>
<% end %>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated..

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You need to add an action to your controller along these lines ([cribbed from here](http://railsforum.com/viewtopic.php?id=28178)):

```
def image
    @material = Material.find(params[:id])
    send_data @material.icon, :type => 'image/png',:disposition => 'inline'
end
```

Then call the path to that action in your `image_tag`.  You obviously need to make sure the `:type` field has the right MIME type, add a route, etc.

Comment: You, sir, deserve cookies!

Comment: Saved me so much time also for postgres if your column is a bytea ActiveRecord::Base.connection.unescape_bytea(file_data)